# System has 32 GB ram but maximum usuage is up to 6 GB

Tags: python, 64-bit, ram, swap, csv

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 (64 bit) and my system has 32 GB RAM. When I run a python (64 bit) program on it, I get a "MemoryError".

the output to `free -m` is:

```
         total        used        free   shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:     31964        5660       23992       61        2311       25805
Swap:     2047           0        2047
```

I am running a genetic programming algorithm for feature selection using csv file with 0.5 Million records. I want to use the full system memory. When I open csv file also with 11+ record it does not show use memory more than 6 GB.

Comment: Is the memory recognized in UEFI/BIOS?

Comment: Yes. It is 32 GB

Comment: Have you tried to open an other instance of your application, to check if Ubuntu will use more than 6 GB? Also, do you have any errors or warnings from your application about not beeing able to allocate memory, or reaching max memory?

Answer (score 0):

The memory usage you're seeing is in line with the system resources allocated to Ubuntu so I'm expecting the problem to be in Python itself: memory fragmentation and garbage cleanup not happening or memory limits set in your Python configuration.

As this has now become more of a programming related [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) question, I'd take it there instead mentioning that from an OS perspective you *should be able to allocate the full memory*.